# Can I block a specific git tag from being pushed to remote in Azure Repos Git?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-tag, azure-repos

My team is using Azure DevOps as our Git server, and is having an issue where a specific unwanted tag keeps being pushed to the remote. We've set up client-side git hooks, and asked everyone on the team to opt in, but it's a large team and seemingly not everyone has done so, because the tag keeps periodically reappearing on the remote. Is there any way the server can be set up to block pushes which would create a specific unwanted tag?

Comment: Git itself does have a general mechanism for this (the pre-receive and update hooks, specifically) but unless you control the actual server host system, you can't use them directly. So it depends on whether Azure provide you something for this; that's an Azure-specific question (to which I don't know the answer).

Comment: Right on, @torek - as best I've been able to ascertain, Azure Repos doesn't support server-side hooks, but I've been wrong when it comes to reading the Azure docs before, so I put the question out in hopes that someone might know something I don't in that regard.

Comment: I'm only half joking here: create the same tag on another commit that you do like. Perhaps the thing pushing it isn't using force (or can't due to permissions).

Comment: BTW, could you say *why* you don't want that tag? If there's something specific about it that you don't want, you may be able to block something else about that commit, besides the tag itself. (For example if it has a big file in it you could block pushes that contain files bigger than X.)

Comment: @TTT it's the tag name itself - someone pushed a tag called "HEAD", which is causing confusion and issues in our pipelines.

Comment: Oh wow. That is unfortunate. Is it always pointing to the same commit or does it move? (If it moves it should be easier to figure out who's doing it, based on the context of the commit getting tagged.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way the server can be set up to block pushes which would create a specific unwanted tag?

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

The Azure devops Git repos currently do not support Git hooks, there is a much-requested user voice about it：

[Add Git pre-receive hooks](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-git-pre-receive-hooks/365841)

And this request is already on the roadmap, I believe that I will meet with us in the near future, You can follow this thread for the latest information：

> On Roadmap means that your feature suggestion has a broad community
> impact and will help improve the product experience. We've allocated
> time for it on our roadmap. We'll update you on the progress.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those, who still looking for the solution today (2024), here is update (Mar 30, 2023) from Microsoft about the [Add Git pre-receive hooks](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-git-pre-receive-hooks/365841) feature request mentioned by Leo Liu:

> There were at least two repository level policies delivered. These are to block pushes where:

> - Commit author e-mail does not match specified patterns
> - File path does match specified patterns

> In general, the pre-receive hooks are a common feature in self-hosted DevOps tools (including GitHub Enterprise Server as well) but not typically supported in SaaS offerings (which Azure DevOps Service is), where running arbitrary customer code on the SaaS’s servers is problematic and raises security concerns.

> For credential scanning, GitHub Advanced Security for Azure DevOps will offer push protections to prevent secrets from being uploaded into repositories. This feature is in private preview now and will be progressing through public preview and general availability in the coming months.

> So, this ticket will be closed soon as we do have no plans to allow customers running their own code on the Azure DevOps Service.

> It is suggested to raise new ask for any specific check that you may find missing.

So, it looks like there is *still* **no way** to achieve this and, more over, it is **not** on the roadmap anymore, unfortunately. ‍♂️